# how to use .env connect to mysql for nextjs

Tags: mysql, reactjs, node.js, next.js

```
const pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 100,
    host: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MYSQL_HOST,
    user: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MYSQL_USER,
    password: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MYSQL_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MYSQL_DATABASE,
});
```

I want you show sample code for me to use .env connect to mysql for nextjs

Answer (score 0):

NEXT_PUBLIC is an environment variable accessible in the browser. Read : https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables

I think that you don't want to display these values.

In your .env or .env.local you can write environment variable as follow:

> MYSQL_HOST="127.0.0.1" // or "192.168.XX.XX" in remote

Then, you can call environment variable like this:

```js
import mysql2 from 'mysql/promise';

export async function callProducts(query, data) {
    try {
      const db = await mysql.createConnection({
        host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
        port: process.env.MYSQL_PORT,
        database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
        user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
        password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD
      })
      const [result] = await db.execute(query, data);
      await db.end();
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return error;
  }
}
```

It works well for me with mariadb.

You can see tutorial of Dr Vipin : https://geniusvipin.medium.com/build-crud-app-with-next-js-server-actions-and-mysql-1e4427dc8800

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).